# Python not reading my file, i'm searching for occurrences of words in a text file

Tags: python

I'm searching occurrences of different words in a text file.

I'm not good at python but i did that on google colab.

```
import os
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive/', force_remount=True)
if not os.path.exists('/content/drive/My Drive/Miserables'):
  os.makedirs('/content/drive/My Drive/Miserables')

root_dir = '/content/drive/My Drive/Miserables/'
os.listdir('/content/drive/My Drive/Miserables')
with open("/content/drive/My Drive/Miserables/miserable.txt", 'r') as f:
     myString = f.readlines()
print(len(myString))
searchWords = ["example"]
for word in searchWords:
    print(f"Word '{word}' appeared {myString.count(word)} time/s.")
```

The thing is python doesnt actually count the number of words, and i have 0 in results when i know that those words are actually in the text.

Can somebody help me please? Thanks you.

Comment: Why is the title in backets? Please [edit] your question and fix any typos/spelling. Also add the output of your program/script. What is the `len` output as?

Comment: `myString` is a *list* of strings, so either the name is mis-leading, or you mistakenly think it is a string.

Comment: The len output is 25229, which is the number of words that my file contains.

Comment: Please [edit] and put any additional info *in the question* and **not** in the comments. Comments tend to get deleted after a while. It is best to have all of the information in one place, rather than spread out over the question and throughout the comments. It makes for less reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is that you use `f.readlines()` to get the file content.

This function returns a list of every line in the file.

e.g.
`["foo foo faa", "faa foo faa"]`

This means youre searching for the word in this list.

Try `f.read()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`f.readlines()` gives you the list with every element representing the line.

For ex. if the text is:

```
I'm here
this is here too
Bye buddy
```

will give you the list:

```
[
 "I'm here",
 "this is here too",
 "Bye buddy"
]
```

To solve it either use `f.read()` instead of `f.readlines()`

```py
import os
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive/', force_remount=True)
if not os.path.exists('/content/drive/My Drive/Miserables'):
  os.makedirs('/content/drive/My Drive/Miserables')

root_dir = '/content/drive/My Drive/Miserables/'
os.listdir('/content/drive/My Drive/Miserables')
with open("/content/drive/My Drive/Miserables/miserable.txt", 'r') as f:
     myString = f.read()
print(len(myString))
searchWords = ["example"]
for word in searchWords:
    print(f"Word '{word}' appeared {myString.count(word)} time/s.")
```

Or

Loop it:

```py
import os
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive/', force_remount=True)
if not os.path.exists('/content/drive/My Drive/Miserables'):
  os.makedirs('/content/drive/My Drive/Miserables')

root_dir = '/content/drive/My Drive/Miserables/'
os.listdir('/content/drive/My Drive/Miserables')
with open("/content/drive/My Drive/Miserables/miserable.txt", 'r') as f:
     myString = f.readlines()
print(len(myString))
searchWords = "example"

count = 0

for i in myString:

    count += i.count(searchWords)
    
print(f"Word '{word}' appeared {count} time/s.")
```